# Collapsible sidebar with Bootstrap 5 was working before but not now

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have this sidebar

[image: viz1]

which should be toggled when the button on the right corner of the photo is clicked. Unfortunately it is not working now but it was worked before. I have no idea what might be the problem.

Here is the HTML output for the sidebar

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="bg-dark h-100" id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-heading bg-dark text-light fw-bold newFont2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-globe me-1"></i> domain.com
    </div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a class="list-group-item bg-sidebar px-3 py-2" href="https://example.com/company/dashboard" current-page="absolute">
        <i class=" fa-solid fa-house-user text-info "></i>
        <span class="align-middle">Home</span>
      </a>
      <a class="list-group-item bg-sidebar px-3 py-2" href="https://example.com/company/dashboard/reviews">
        <i class=" fa-solid fa-star-half-stroke "></i>
        <span class="align-middle">Reviews</span>
      </a>
      <a class="list-group-item bg-sidebar px-3 py-2" href="https://example.com/company/dashboard/invitations">
        <i class=" fa-solid fa-envelope "></i>
        <span class="align-middle">Invitations</span>
      </a>
      <a class="list-group-item bg-sidebar px-3 py-2" href="https://example.com/company/dashboard/settings">
        <i class=" fa-solid fa-wrench "></i>
        <span class="align-middle">Settings</span>
      </a>
      <div class="border-top my-3" href="#"></div>
      <div class="plan-overview px-3">
        <span class="text-white-50 newFont d-block">Selected plan: <span class="fw-bold text-light">Expert Plan</span>
          <br>Available actions: <span class="fw-bold text-light ">646 left</span>
          <br>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here's the button

```
<button class="btn navbar-toggler2" id="sidebarToggle"><i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i></button>
```

I'm using **Bootstrap v5.0.2**. I can actually see following the scripts that are loaded on the page, that I'm using something called Simple Sidebar

```
/*!
* Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar v6.0.3 (https://startbootstrap.com/template/simple-sidebar)
* Copyright 2013-2021 Start Bootstrap
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",(e=>{const t=document.body.querySelector("#sidebarToggle");t&&t.addEventListener("click",(e=>{e.preventDefault(),document.body.classList.toggle("sb-sidenav-toggled"),localStorage.setItem("sb|sidebar-toggle",document.body.classList.contains("sb-sidenav-toggled"))}))}));
```

Comment: Please add an [example].

Comment: Is there something preventing clicks from making it to the button? Can you add an event listener via the console to confirm the button is getting the click? `document.querySelector('#sidebarToggle').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('got clicked'))`.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/y7jChkV.png It detects the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if on click of the button, does body toggles class `sb-sidenav-toggled`, if it does, check your css as it works on css, the `#sidebar-wrapper` should get `margin-left` after the class toggles.

Otherwise it's js problem, not loaded/somethings stops it before it get's triggered, or some errors within ?

**EDIT:**

So it was just something preventing or not declared properly onclick, so declaring on click was solution:

```
$("#sidebarToggle").on('click', function() {$('body').toggleClass('sb-sidenav-toggled');});
```

Comment: The body toggles no class on button click. Literally nothing happens. I get in the console `This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”.` which has nothing to do with the sidebar.

Comment: Check for javascript errors, maybe something stops it before it gets triggered, maybe `navbar-toggler2` remove it?

Comment: Still not working after removing `navbar-toggler2`. Is there any chance some JS code missing or what might be the problem?

Comment: There's high chance of missing something, or there's something declared that stops triggering the code you showed to us

Comment: try adding/removing manually class `sb-sidenav-toggled` to body, just to see if it triggers the action? If not, you will need to reproduce error somewhere so we can test it..

Comment: Added `sb-sidenav-toggled` to the body's class and the sidebar doesn't show on page load. In this case can't I just use a jQuery `toggleClass` on the button and it will toggle `sb-sidenav-toggled` on the body?

Comment: `$("#sidebarToggle").on('click', function() {$('body').toggleClass('sb-sidenav-toggled');});` did it. Thank you so much @Ultrazz008 ! Edit your answer so I can mark it.